# cannot get to next line within shell script

Tags: bash

In interactive shell:

```
echo -e "hello\nworld"
hello
world
```

doing the same thing within a script, I cant get to next next line

```
hello world
```

Actually, all the following work to get to next line in interactive shell but not within a script (I never had this issue before):

```
echo 
echo -e 
echo -e "\n"
printf "\n"
```

on centos 8:

```
/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

on debian buster (I dont have any issue on debian!):

```
/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

script syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

script launch:

```
./script
```

Comment: Please include a demonstration script showing this problem (just two or three lines should be sufficient)  along with the expected and actual outputs, and also show how you call it

Comment: echo exists as `/bin/echo`, and also as a built-in for various shells. Those versions are not necessarily identical. The same is true of `printf`. You should post which shell runs in your terminal, any shebang on your script, and whether you run the script as itself or by specifying like `sh myScript`. Also, which distro, and the output from `alias echo`. And `./myScript | od -t x1ac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pb solved thanx to you guys: issue occurs on centos 8 with /usr/bin/bash not /bin/bash (I havent tried to repro on debian buster).